# Automatic rights change when virtual COM ports are enumerated

Tags: chmod, ttyusb, composite

I am developing a uC device which enumerates as three virtual COMs (actually it is a composite device). Everything works perfect except one small thing. Those ports belong to the `dialout` group and can be accesses only if the user has the root privileges or belongs to this group. Is there any way of automatic rights or group change during the enumeration?

Comment: Use custom udev rules. Google for details, tutorials and/or similar questions on stackexchange. While you are at it, you may also want symlinks with a custom name.

Comment: @dirkt - thank you. All works perfect. Please convert your comment to the answer.

Comment: It's actually a duplicate - there's a lot of questions on this. If you could find a duplicate question and link to it, you'd do me a favour and save a bit of my time.

Comment: Note, the dialout group was created for this purpose. You are simply supposed to add this group to the user ids you want to have access. `sudo usermod -a -G dialout theuser`

Comment: @meuh I know it. But the problem is that, but I want to avoid it (the user has to know what to do)